# Phototransistor receiver circuit output display 0 V

Tags: arduino, operational-amplifier, photodiode, phototransistor, differential-amplifier

I am working on a sensor for my university project. The output displays 0 V, but when I put the light in, the value changes. When I put it in the box, it displays 0 V again. I am working with an Arduino Mega 2560. I asked my professor for help, and she told me to add a differential amplifier to the output. I should then enter the output of the first op amp into a non-inverting amplifier. I have used the LM358N, but I am struggling with the circuit of the two op amps. I do not know what resistors to use, and I am using the Arduino's 5 V supply (V+) and GND (V-). Can you please help me with the circuits to amplify the 0 V to 4 V? Here is the receiver circuit that displays 0 V in the analog branch, and the second photo is what my professor suggested I do.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You've got your photodiode forward biased.